# Private property declaration in your class implementation?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Sorry if it's too obvious for you. I'm still learning objetive-c and proper design patterns.
Could you explain me why it is a good idea to declare a property inside `@interface` in implementation file of a class as a private property? You just can use a local declaration of your type with a class scope, since nobody outside your class would use any getter or setter for this property.

Thanks.

Comment: What do yo mean by 'a local declaration of your type with a class scope'?

Comment: Have you tried searching on the web by any chance or flipping through apple docs?

Comment: [?](http://d.images.memegenerator.net/instances/500x/14507811.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the property semantics, you get memory management behavior handled 'for free' by the compiler. Even if your data is private within your class, having the compiler emit correct release/retain/copy saves time and mistakes down the line.

With the modern ARC compiler, this is probably less of an issue now.

Comment: So for me doesn't make sense using properties inside implementation. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

When you declare something as `@private`, usually an instance variable or a property, it became only accessible in methods of the class that declared it. Trying to access it from a subclass results in an error.

I know you didn't asked for this but there is also `@protected`, when a property is declared like this, it becomes only accessible in methods of the class that declared it and in the methods of any class that inherits from that class.

The source for this info is the best book I know about Objective-C - [Learning Objective-C 2.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321711386) by Robert Clair.